# WP8.1 and interceptors

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, interceptor

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app and I have to check some informations before executing some methods (I have to check if the internet connection is available and if the localization is active).
There are interceptors or another way to programmatically execute a method before some actions in wp8.1?

Comment: What "actions"? There is a difference between checking for availability and reacting to events.

Comment: I have to execute this method before every method that requires the internet connection or the geolocalization

Comment: Have a property on a static network helper class somewhere called IsNetworkAvailable (which checks if network is available, obviously) and do "if (IsNetworkAvailable) { //some code }". Of course, have in mind that the fact that you did or did not have network available during IsNetworkAvailable check still could change by the time you actually make the network call. I am not aware of a better, more automatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET platform has something called Code Contracts. Basically, starting from .NET 4.0, you can use `Contract.Requires(Boolean)` to verify if a precondition is active. You can even show a special message to the user when it's not active.

For more info, there's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx on MSDN, and of course Google.

Comment: To my understanding, this is not a use-case for Code Contracts. CC are to *ensure* that guarantees [pre/post/invariant] are in place to ["Improve testability, Allow static verification, Provide API documentation"](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/), not to provide handling of resource requirements or management of such dependencies.

Comment: I checked the examples from the different sources. Code Contracts are also used in those examples to check for preconditions (like Requires(x != null)). There's no reason why you cannot use it for network availability tests as well, since that's the same concept.